# Why does a nested Omit type lose type safety?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript does not check a nested type when I use `Omit` on the type. See `register` vs `registerWithOmit` in this example:

```
export type CaseOptions = {
    caseA: { a: number };
    caseB: { b: number };
};

type Options = { name: string } & (Omit<CaseOptions, 'caseA'> | Omit<CaseOptions, 'caseB'>);

function register(options: Options) {}

// As expected: this fails as caseA is invalid 
register({ name: 'myName', caseA: { b: 1 } });


function registerWithOmit(options: Omit<Options, 'name'>) {}

// Should fail because caseA is invalid
registerWithOmit({ caseA: { b: 1 } });
```

Why is that the case?

This could be solved differently, e.g., with a type guard, but I am interested in why the type system behaves this way.

Try it here: [TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBDAzsA8mGASwgDss4BeOAbwCg4G4BjbYAQQC4a4MuSBXALYAjYFDgBfANz1GLHACEu1OML5DR46bW20kKOPiKlyVFSQyDgXLDCiESAc0lwAZHAAUuQYRgAeTBwjYjIAGjgAcnl2CIA+OAAfQx9-QLwCEKxwqNYFOIBKGVoAM34SJmMSOChgR0JbMQ8IDJMuYJN8mglaWgB6Xrg2clAUCuAAEy4YAAt6uGKMQgAbcmxmVjY4OYcANwwlwnG4Whq6hqgPc0trSMFEADlriPDozm41OABGFwl8npKyhUQtVavUYGIAOq+abeXxNFpkNopPztMKRCxWApdHr9OAAZWmEH4SyOC2WqmALH4OHWOE22xIewO4xOoPOUJmsJgl1p7GUqi43wkkj+-yAA)

Comment: [This playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQD1w) contains an explanation. If it doesn't explain this behavior, what am I missing?

Comment: And as a bonus, you can solve it without a type guard with a distributive omit variant: https://tsplay.dev/WGArKN

Comment: It took me a while, but now I understand: The problem is that `keyof` only returns the common keys of a union type. The only common key in `Options` is `name`.

Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite hard to grasp what is happening if we can't actually see what `Options` is. We can make TypeScript show the type in full with `infer` like this:

```
type Options = ({ name: string } & (Omit<CaseOptions, 'caseA'> | Omit<CaseOptions, 'caseB'>)) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Then we'll see that the type `Options` is actually

```
{
    name: string;
    caseB: {
        b: number;
    };
} | {
    name: string;
    caseA: {
        a: number;
    };
}
```

`keyof` can be a trap to newcomers. One might think that `keyof` would get the keys of `Options` as `"name" | "caseB" | "caseA"`, but there's something you need to consider first! Imagine we have a variable `key` that is of type `keyof Options`. That means indexing into something of type `Options` should be safe:

```
options[key] // should be OK
```

But wait, if `keyof Options` gave you `"name" | "caseB" | "caseA"`, then it's no longer safe, since this could be possible!

```
options["caseA"] // unsafe, since caseA is not guaranteed to exist
```

The only safe key to use is `name` since it exists on both members in the union. That is why `keyof` actually only gets the shared keys. In this case, it's only `"name"`.

The next step in understanding why this doesn't work as expected is in the definition of `Omit`:

```
type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }
```

If we then "expand" your usage of `Omit<Options, "name">`, we get this:

```
{ [P in Exclude<"name", "name">]: Options[P] }
```

Since we are excluding `"name"` from `"name"`, we get `never`! And a mapped type over `never` is really just `{}`, the "empty object type". However, this type actually has a quirk... Anything that is not null or undefined is assignable to `{}`, which is why the following works:

```
// same as
// function registerWithOmit(options: {}) { }
function registerWithOmit(options: Omit<Options, 'name'>) { }

// This is OK since anything that is not null or undefined is assignable to {}
registerWithOmit({ caseA: { b: 1 } })
```

As such, to get around this, you will need an `Omit` that distributes over a union and operates on each of its members, instead of operating on the entire union at once. This is pretty easy to do, thanks to [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends T ? Omit<T, K> : never;
```

We use `T extends T` to distribute over the union, and then use each member (still `T`, I know, it's a bit confusing) in `Omit`. Essentially, if we use `DistributiveOmit<A | B, "name">`, it will "expand to"

```
(A extends A | B ? Omit<A, "name"> : never) | (B extends A | B ? Omit<B, "name"> : never)
```

which simplifies to

```
Omit<A, "name"> | Omit<B, "name">
```

Then it'll work as expected:

```
// Type of `options` parameter is 
// {
//     caseB: {
//         b: number;
//     };
// } | {
//     caseA {
//         a: number;
//     };
// }
function registerWithOmit(options: DistributiveOmit<Options, 'name'>) {}

// Should fail because caseA is invalid
registerWithOmit({ caseA: { b: 1 } })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGArKN)