# How would you parse this TypeScript `DistributiveOmit` type/expression?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

How would you explain/describe/narrate/parse in your head the following TypeScript expression:

```
export type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends any ? Omit<T, K> : never;
```

(It is defined [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/packages/mui-types) and is located in the `index.d.ts` file)

Even though, questions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449738/why-does-a-nested-omit-type-lose-type-safety/74451147#74451147) and question [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103834/typescript-omit-a-property-from-all-interfaces-in-a-union-but-keep-the-union-s) explain what and how unions work, I am mostly curious how would one parse this particular TS expression.

Comment: That's really funny since I explained it in the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74451147/18244921) earlier today.

Comment: Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103834/typescript-omit-a-property-from-all-interfaces-in-a-union-but-keep-the-union-s) by jcalz which answers the same thing.

Comment: "Given `T` and some potential keys, distribute over `T` and return `Omit<T, K>`." is how I would think about it... but that's clearly lacking a lot of detail. This is really a more opinionated question now, which is not really suitable for Stack overflow.